# jQuery / CSS - Add class on validation

Tags: jquery, html, css

I think i have a simple issue. I have a set of fields on my form:

```
<input class="one-third" id="Firstname" type="text"/>
```

When one of these fields are blank, my validation should highlight the field (red boarder).

I have attempted the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/oampz/Ybxk2/1/

```
$(".submitForm").click(function() {

    if($("#Firstname").val() == ''){
        alert('Input can not be left blank');

        $("#Firstname").addClass("highlight");
    }   

    //document.forms[0].submit();

});
```

But it doesnt seem to work.

Should i be removing my original class?

Thanks

Comment: I don't know why this question was downvoted, he tried, he shared his code, as well as the demo, he wasn't aware of specificity, anyways upvoted, wasn't a candidate to downvote..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**NO**, you don't have to remove original classes.. specificity is the issue there, so you will need a more specific selector.

`input[type="text"]` Overrides `.highlight`

---

```
input[type=text].highlight {
    font-size:150%;
    color:red;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ybxk2/2/)

---

Don't know what's specificity? [Learn Here](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/)..

If you want to calculate specificity, [here's](http://specificity.keegan.st/) an handy tool, if you feed your selectors in there, the score for `input[type="text"]` will be *11* whereas for `.highlight` is *10*

Comment: @OamPsy Don't worry, it's an absolute perfect question and you welcome :)

Comment: @user3004356 You shouldn't answer here, comment on your question, I provided you the link because you have a similar issue

Comment: @user3004356 Comment over [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21450977/1542290), not here, this is not your question, I just told you to refer this because you are not able to understand specificity, so don't comment here, comment on the answer I posted on your question

Answer (score 1):

`!important` tells the browser to overwrite any CSS rules that affect the property.

```
.highlight {
    font-size:150%;
    color:red!important;
    border: 1px solid red!important;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ybxk2/3/)

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest you to keep the changing styles in two different classes instead of overriding as shown by Mr.Alien.

something like `.green` and `.red`.

```
.green{
    border: 1px solid #ababab;
}

.red{
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

This will help you not to get confuse.

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ybxk2/8/)

In short, don't keep the **changing styes** as *common style* to all elements. Not a good design.