# How to change the highlight color of textbox using focus selector in css

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm new to **CSS**. I have a input text field where I need to change the color of the border from red to another color. I used focus selector in **CSS** and was not successful.
**Below is the input field :**

```
<label>Phone<font color="red">*</font></label><br>
<span>
    <input id="element_4_1" name="element_4_1" class="element text" size="3" maxlength="3" value=""  type="text"> -
</span>
<span>
    <input id="element_4_2" name="element_4_2" class="element text" size="4" maxlength="4" value="" type="text"> -
</span>
<span>
    <input id="element_4_3" name="element_4_3" class="element text" size="10" maxlength="10" value=""  type="text" required >
</span>
```

**And the css :**

```
.element text:focus {
  border-color: #66afe9;
  outline: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 8px rgba(102, 175, 233, 0.6);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 8px rgba(102, 175, 233, 0.6);
}
```

**Edit :**
When I click submit form, as it is a required field, this shows red if empty. 
Now it is not working. How can I change the highlight color of the textbox when I focus on it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Obviously it won't work as your selector is wrong, you are using `.element text` which selects an element of <s>`<text>`</s>*(Invalid tag)* which is nested inside element having a `class` `.element` it should be

```
.element.text:focus
      --^--
 /* No space as well */
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/4TcY3/)

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/4TcY3/1/) *(Making it lil cleaner)*

[**Demo 3**](http://jsfiddle.net/4TcY3/2/) *(Animating the `:focus`)*

```
span input[type="text"]:focus { /* You can also use .element.text:focus here */
  border-color: #66afe9;
  outline: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 8px rgba(102, 175, 233, 0.6);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 8px rgba(102, 175, 233, 0.6);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `.element text:focus` which selects nothing because there is no element like text in `.element`. Instead of this you have to use `.element.text:focus`
for eg.

```
.element.text:focus{
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`.` is missing from `text` class and try pointing from input

```
input.text:focus {
  border-color: green;
  outline: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 8px rgba(102, 175, 233, 0.6);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 8px rgba(102, 175, 233, 0.6);
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/AlOwaduD/2/)**